# How can i display the same value of a char in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net

Hello good day sir and mam I just creating a hangman game using visual basic but unfortunately I can't print the same value of a char that I want to be printed.
Example : the word to be guess is : apple when I click letter p only the first letter P appear that's why I want to know how can I get the second value thank you :)

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    If startgame = True Then
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then

        Else

            If TextBox1.Text.ToUpper.Contains(first1) And Letter1.Text = "" And first1 <> "" Then
                Letter1.Text = first1
                truetry += 1

                CheckForWinning()
            ElseIf TextBox1.Text.ToUpper.Contains(second2) And Letter2.Text = "" And second2 <> "" Then
                Letter2.Text = second2
                truetry += 1
                CheckForWinning()
            ElseIf TextBox1.Text.ToUpper.Contains(third3) And Letter3.Text = "" And third3 <> "" Then
                Letter3.Text = third3
                truetry += 1
                CheckForWinning()
            ElseIf TextBox1.Text.ToUpper.Contains(fourth4) And Letter4.Text = "" And fourth4 <> "" Then
                Letter4.Text = fourth4
                truetry += 1
                CheckForWinning()
            ElseIf TextBox1.Text.ToUpper.Contains(fifth5) And Letter5.Text = "" And fifth5 <> "" Then
                Letter5.Text = fifth5
                truetry += 1
                CheckForWinning()
            ElseIf TextBox1.Text.ToUpper.Contains(sixth6) And Letter6.Text = "" And sixth6 <> "" Then
                Letter6.Text = sixth6
                truetry += 1
                CheckForWinning()
            Else
                falsetry += 1
                StartDrawingWhenLosing (falsetry)
                label11.Text = label11.Text & " " & TextBox1.Text
            End If
        End If
    Else

    End If
    TextBox1.Text = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you explain a little further?

Comment: sir i want the same value to be printed out instead of only one like 
example is tree 
  in my case i just get the first value of e not  the second one 
sorry sir newbie

Comment: The problem is that you're using `ElseIf`, so you stop looking as soon as you find the first match. You need multiple independent `If` blocks so that every one gets checked no matter what.

Comment: ohhh okay okay i will try it thanks sir